# Polarization type of the complement abelian subvariety

Tags: reference-request, abelian-varieties

Assume that $P$ is a Prym variety of a ramified double cover (hence not principally polarized). Let $A,B\subset P$ a complementary pair. Assume that the type of the polarization of $A$ is given by $\delta$ and that $dim A < dim B$.

> Can one deduce the type of the polarization on B?

If $P$ were pp,this is well known.